# Пройдите в квадрате от ячейки 1 в ячейку 2 так, чтобы посетить все клетки по одному разу, не попадая в черные

Tags: c, алгоритм

[image: <code>введите сюда описание изображения</code>]

```
int main()
{


    int array[R][S];

    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<R; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<S; j++)
        {
            array[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    array[0][1]=1; //точка 1
    array[3][5]=2; //точка 2

    array[0][0]=-1; // чорная т1
    array[4][3]=-1; // чорная т2

    for (i=0; i<R; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<S; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d\t ",array[i][j]);
        }
       printf("\n");
    }


    printf("\n\n");


    for (i=0; i<R; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<S; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d\t ",array[i][j]);
        }
       printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сговорились, да? :) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607771/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5?s=4|0.0000

Comment: понятия не имею о чем вы :)

Comment: @Harry тут еще) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607732/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5

Comment: @user123 напишите, пожалуйста, комментарии к своему коду, что именно у вас не работает

Comment: хм. ну, или сессия)

Comment: создал матрицу 6x6, черные клетки имеют значение  -1, точка 1 ->1, точка 2->2 не знаю как пройти белым точкам по  т.1 к т.2 так чтобы посетить все белые клетки по одному разу

Comment: @Matty Так и там тоже я решал :) Двух лабиринтов с меня на сегодня хватит...

Comment: Посмотрите там, куда у показал, возьмите программу, посмотрите, как работает, и примените к своей задаче... Она ну очень похожа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А, ладно, быстренько дописал третий лабиринт :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int Tgt = 110;
const int I   = Tgt;

int m[6][6]={
    {2,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,2,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0}
};

struct Coord
{
    int r = 0, c = 0;
    Coord(int r = 0, int c = 0):r(r),c(c){}
};

const int STOP = 34; //36 - 2;

Coord path[STOP];

bool step(int r, int c, int level)
{
    if (level == STOP - 1)
    {
        if (r == 3 && c == 5)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < level; ++i)
            {
                cout << "(" << path[i].r  << "," << path[i].c << ") - ";
            }
            cout << "(3,5)\n";
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    m[r][c] = 1;


    path[level] = Coord(r,c);

    if (c > 0 && m[r][c-1] == 0)
    {
        if (step(r,c-1,level+1)) return true;
    }
    if (c < 5 && m[r][c+1] == 0)
    {
        if (step(r,c+1,level+1)) return true;
    }
    if (r > 0 && m[r-1][c] == 0)
    {
        if (step(r-1,c,level+1)) return true;
    }
    if (r < 5 && m[r+1][c] == 0)
    {
        if (step(r+1,c,level+1)) return true;
    }
    m[r][c] = 0;
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    step(0,1,0);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пометить ответ как принятый не получается? :)